# Stretch elements by overflow in jasperreports

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a structure like bellow which consist of one static text and two text fields. The text fields should expand relative to their content. I need to adjust them in a way that these three elements expand together.  Should I keep them in one band? What should be the stretch type for each?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Put all three elements in a band.
- Set the `Stretch Type` of `Static Text` to `Relative To Band Height`.
- Set the same for `text field 1`.
- Set the same for `text field 2` and additionally set `Position Type` to `Float`.